# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EnsureDeleted will cause Crash when not attached to debugger

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, entity-framework-core

Have a Xamarin.Forms project using EntityFrameworkCore for the onboard db. On startup of the app we will call:

```
Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

Which will reset the onboard db when needed. When running for iOS and Android this will run fine when connected to the debugger. As soon as I disconnect the cord from the device and just run the app it will crash on load and I've singled it out to the EnsureDeleted being the issue, if I comment out that line it will work fine. Also I just put an empty try catch around it and it will still crash the entire app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be related to this issue:

github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3112

Which was introduced in the 16.1 release of VS 2019.

Following the steps in this post: github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3112#issuecomment-495780758
With version 9.2.3.0 of the Xamarin Android SDK, fixed the crash.

Comment: It did sound similar. It’s just that it’s happening for iOS for me as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @Matt I can not found this issue in IOS, I advice you could fix this issue in android by above the link firstly, then test again in IOS and android, if this issue is still existed in IOS, you can open a new thread for the issue in IOS platform.In the end, it the reply is helpful, please do not mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.